# Setting registry key doesn't work. Sometimes

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to set a registry key in my C# code, but it doesn't work all the time. Sometimes it does work, sometimes it doesn't. I'm starting to get crazy...
In previous projects I had no problems writing and reading to the registry, but I do now.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
string newVersion = "10A";
RegistryKey key = null;
try
{
    key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\stuff1\\stuff2 " + newVersion + "\\" + newVersion + "\\stuff3\\Settings", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
    key.SetValue("CopyConvertDone", "1", RegistryValueKind.String);
    key.Flush();
    rep.Message("CopyConvertDone registry key set for revision: " + newVersion);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    rep.Error(e);
}
finally
{
    if (key != null)
    {
        key.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        rep.Error("Registry key is set to null.");
    }
}
```

What I already tried but didn't work: 
- Instead of using CreateSubKey I tried OpenSubKey with the write-parameter set to true.
- Added the .Flush() method.
- Did a Thread.Pause(2000) to give it some time before progressing my program (which needs this registry key)

I don't get any error and the subkey already exists, but the value (CopyConvertDone) doesn't.

Can anyone see a problem in this code and has a possible solution?

Comment: Can you clarify what happens when it fails- are you getting an exception of some kind or just no change in the registry?

Comment: Is the above code being called actually?

Answer (score 3):

The code looks alright to me, however if it's working some of the time then perhaps use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what calls are being made to the registry and what is succeeding/failing.

Answer (score 2):

Had something similar happen to me just now, and using Process Monitor as suggested by Antony I discovered Windows 7 was redirecting my writes to a key under `HKCU\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE`.

Just a pointer in case anybody else has this issue.

Comment: See this SO answer for the explanation why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10941367/155167

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct. Maybe try to remove Flush. From MSDN: `An application should only call Flush if it must be absolute certain that registry changes are recorded to disk. In general, Flush rarely, if ever, need be used.`

Your already closing the RegistryKey in the finally statement.